# ExtJS 4 - Last item of accordion doesn't have x-accordion-hd-last-collapsed class

Tags: extjs, accordion, extjs4

I'm working on a ExtJS 4 project (MVC) and I have a navigation panel (panel with layout accordion).

My problem is that unlike the accordion layout example, my last item doesn't have a `x-accordion-hd-last-collapsed` class (and other classes).

First I thought it could be because i was extending the Panel... then I copied the code accordion code from the example and used it on my project and it still missing those classes.

I have the following logic structure:

```
viewport (layout border)
|-- header (defined component, north)
|-- accordion (west)
|-- tabpanel (center)
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was including the ext-core.js and the ext-all-debug.js manually instead of using the boostrap.js. Apparently it solved the issue, go figure...